# LoadLibrary doesn't load the module globally

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I have the scenario that I would like to create a new process with `CreateProcessW` and the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag. After that I inject an DLL with `CreateRemoteThread` that calls `LoadLibraryA`. The DLL starts fine and the Process that injected the DLL waits for the DLL to finish it's jobs. Then the new process just get's resumed. All this works just fine. However I have noticed that if the injected DLL calls `LoadLibraryA ('advapi.dll')` for example (while the main thread/process is supsended) that the Module is not loaded into the process. Why is that?

Comment: You're not calling LoadLibrary() from DllMain, are you?

Comment: I forgot about that. That was it. I needed to add the code to the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. Thank you very much!

Comment: Since the process was created suspended, nothing in the process has started initializing. In particular, the data structures used by `LoadLibrary` have not been initialized.